# Setting a low max memory size for SQL 2012 Developer edition

Tags: sql-server-2012, memory

I tried to limit the Max Memory size for a local instance of SQL 2012 Dev edition to 64 MB but two things happened: 1) the value reverted to 128 MB when I tried to save and 2) the server kind of died. It stopped responding and the service had to be restarted. Then it came back to life until I tried to set lower than 128 MB max memory, and so on. Is it possible to set lower than 128 MB max memory and how?

This talks about absolute maximum memory, but says nothing of the lowest value:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at `sys.configurations` you will see that the minimum value for max server memory is 128 MB.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = 'max server memory (MB)'
```

What will happen if you attempt to run `RECONFIGURE` after setting the value smaller than that is that it will bump to the lowest possible value. At that point 128 MB may not be enough for SQL to function, and so it becomes unresponsive.

You can set it to 64 MB by using `RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE` but at that point you may not even be able to start SQL Server in order to fix that up, so I would not recommend doing do.

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely not possible to set `max server memory (MB)` lower than 128MB, *without causing SQL Server to have problems starting*.

Running `EXEC sys.sp_configure 'max server memory (MB)';` shows the minimum is 128.